# Error for some (but not all) websites in IIS: Unable to make the session state request to the session state server

Tags: .net, iis, session-state

Problem here.
Session state in Services running fine and all websites in IIS running smoothly.
3 websites in IIS (same server), let's call it website A, B and C

Then website A received too much traffic.
Website A remains working
Website B and C shows this session state error

> Unable to make the session state request to the session state server. Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the client and server ports are the same. If the server is on a remote machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection. If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the server name.

How did I solve this?
I stopped IIS for website A, and then website B and C immediately start to work.
It seems that website A is sucking resources away from website B and C

Anyone know how to solve this, so that each website can have fixed amount of resources?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> How did I solve this? I stopped IIS for website A, and then website B and C immediately start to work. It seems that website A is sucking resources away from website B and C
>   Anyone know how to solve this, so that each website can have fixed amount of resources?

As far as I know, there is no build-in featuer to  fixed amount of session resources. I suggest you could try to limit the websites A's session timeout time and the website A's current request to aovid it use so many resources.

You could reduce the website A's sessin timeout value and max concurrent connection volume.

Deatails, you could refer to below image:

1.Open the IIS management console and locate the web site A's session state

[image]

2.Modify the timeout value.

[image]

3.Modify the advanced setting for the web site A.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am trying out your suggestion